# Using Solace with Bitronix JTA Transaction Manager

Tags: java, spring, solace, bitronix

Currently using Bitronix to manage JDBC (Oracle) and JMS (ActiveMQ). Now looking to swap out ActiveMQ for Solace but can't find any examples of using Bitronix with Solace. Just wondering if anyone has any experience of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Bitronix's [documentation](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/Overview), two methods of integration are allowed.
Solace's JMS API supports both, so this should work.

1. Spring

   - Solace's Spring integration guide can be found [here](http://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/spring-framework/).
2. Directly via JMS

   - `com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl` is Solace's implementation of `javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory`.